# Connecting DELL N1548 to HP Core switch with LAN

Tags: vlan, hp, dell, switchport, lldp

I currently have a setup with a HP core switch with few VLANs configured on it e.g. vlan 10, 20, 30, 40.

However when I uplink my DELL N1548 to the HP core switch, I cannot connect anything behind the DELL switch, do I need to configure vlan on the DELL switch? I have tried configured those vlans on the Dell switch and configured the switchport as general or trunk mode, both configuration not working as expected.

The one who configured the core switch has left, and there was no documentation left behind. I am trying my best to learn and configured so that it works, however after few days of trying, I am out of clue.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add those VLANs to the Dell Switch.  The commands to do so are likely the same (or you could try managing the device via the web browser which is likely easier if you are not comfortable.)

Once you have created those VLANs on the switch, you need to make sure the connection between the Dell and the HP is a trunk link.  There are access ports and trunk ports.  Access ports are for devices like PCs, printers, etc.  Trunk ports connect to other switches and occasionally IP phones.

Next, assign the VLAN (for example, VLAN 10) to one of the ports on the Dell.  Plug in a device.  If everything else is correct, it should work.  You can also try assigning a static IP on that VLAN on this port to see if just DHCP is an issue at this point.

If you have the trunk configured on both switches, and you have an access port configured, and you still aren't getting anywhere, you will want to make sure the VLANs are allowed on the trunk by both sides.  Typically, the default setting for the trunk will allow ALL VLANs over the trunk, so you shouldn't have to do anything here.

If you're still stuck, we'll need to see sanitized (no company info) configurations for these ports and the switches in general most likely.

Answer (score 0):

When you connect the Dell switch to a VLAN trunk on the HP you need to configure the VLANs in the exact same way. If you don't you can only use the HP's native/untagged VLAN on the Dell which may be none.

Also, you need to check whether the Dell's downlink port already has any interfering configuration, e.g. BPDU guard, link aggregation.

If the physical link comes up you can check the switch's MAC table for each VLAN to see if it gets populated across the trunk.

For specific help you'll need to add the (sanitized) switch configurations and the used ports to your question.